PDFLatex: Cell content missing when multirow is too big
All cells that merge too many rows have this issue. For example, this cell will be empty, instead of having the text "258 (0x102)":
\multirow{70}{=}{
   \textbf{258 (0x102)}
}

For cells that are only a few rows long, this problem doesn't occur.

Please add a compilable [mre] to your question
